# Installation of RosAria in ROS kinect

Tags: kinect, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorial of RoaAria [How to start ROSARIA](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA) . First, I brought RosAria into the workspace. Then I installed the ARIA from Adept MobileRobots. When I tried to build rosaria using catkin_make, I encountered the following error.

```
CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/LaserPublisher.cpp.o: In function `LaserPublisher::publishPointCloud()':
LaserPublisher.cpp:(.text+0x112b): undefined reference to `ArRangeBuffer::getBuffer[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/build.make:156: recipe for target '/home/tezhang/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosaria/RosAria' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/tezhang/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosaria/RosAria] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3376: recipe for target 'rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Is it because of the new version ROS kinect or my wrong steps installing rosaria? Is there any way I can fix this problem? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235404/installation-of-rosaria-in-ros-kinect/) by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also possibly related: [ROSARIA -- Impossible to Install](http://answers.ros.org/question/235418)

Disclaimer: I answered it in that thread.

---

Originally posted by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) with karma: 258 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on 2016-05-28**:
Thank you very much! It works for me.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2016-05-31**:
Note that libaria packages for newer Ubuntu versions (e.g. 16.04) will be released sometime in the future, check back at http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Aria to see if they become available (will also be announced on aria-users list and news section of that site.)